# why subprocess.check_output raise an error CalledProcessError

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I tried lot of different way but i can't figure out this problem..i am not expert in python can any one explain how can i solve this problem...plzzz

```
command = "netsh wlan show profile"
ssid = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
ssid = ssid.decode("utf-8")
ssid_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', ssid)
for ssid_name in ssid_list:
    subprocess.check_output(["netsh","wlan","show","profile",ssid_name,"key=clear"])
```

**and it gives error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Prakash/Desktop/Hacking tool/Execute_sys_cmd_payload.py", line 18, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["netsh","wlan","show","profile",ssid_name,"key=clear"])
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', 'Prakash_WiFi\r', 'key=clear']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried executing that same command in a shell to see if it gives any error output? Also, you can [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your post to make it easier to read. For example, highlighting code and error messages; bringing them apart from normal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `check_output` this exception will be raised whenever a command extis abnormally, as indicated by a non-zero return code.

A possible solution is to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead. This will run the process and return a [`CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) instance, which has a `returncode` attribute that you can check;

```
import subprocess as sp

command = ["netsh","wlan","show",ssid_name,"key=clear"]
netsh = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)
if netsh.returncode != 0:
    print(f'netsh error: {netsh.returncode}')
else:
   # process netsh.stdout.
```

From reading [this page](https://www.computerhope.com/netsh.htm), it seems that the command you should use is `netsh wlan show` (without profile).

Comment: thank you for your valuable comment...and its worked :-)